# Cocos2d in iOS 6 simulator

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios6, sigabrt

I was writing a simple program using Tiled Map Editor Cocos2d and Xcode and last time I tried it it worked but now I got the new iOS 6 simulator and it doesn't. The error is just "Sigbrt"  it means the signal to abort. I don't know what's wrong with my program. Here's the Hellowrold.h

```
//
//  HelloWorldLayer.h
//  game
//
//  Created by Alex Reichenbach on 9/29/12.
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2012. All rights reserved.
//


// When you import this file, you import all the cocos2d classes
#import "cocos2d.h"

// HelloWorldLayer
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer
{
    CCTMXTiledMap *theMap;
    CCTMXLayer *bounds;
    CCTMXLayer *bgLayer;

}
@property (nonatomic,retain) CCTMXTiledMap *theMap;
@property (nonatomic,retain) CCTMXLayer *bounds;
@property (nonatomic,retain) CCTMXLayer *bgLayer;


// returns a CCScene that contains the HelloWorldLayer as the only child
+(CCScene *) scene;

@end
```

Here's the HellowWorldLayer.m

```
//
//  HelloWorldLayer.m
//  game
//
//  Created by Alex Reichenbach on 9/29/12.
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2012. All rights reserved.
//


// Import the interfaces
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"

// HelloWorldLayer implementation
@implementation HelloWorldLayer
@synthesize theMap;
@synthesize bgLayer;
@synthesize bounds;

+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

// add layer as a child to scene
[scene addChild: layer];

// return the scene
return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init])) {


        self.theMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"game.tmx"];
        self.bgLayer = [theMap layerNamed:@"bg"];

        self.bounds = [_theMap layerNamed:@"by"];

        [self addChild:theMap z:-1];


}
return self;
}

// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
- (void) dealloc
{
    self.theMap = nil;
    self.bgLayer = nil;
    self.bounds = nil;
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

and here's the Tiled program

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="32" height="54" tilewidth="10" tileheight="10">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="Solid_blue" tilewidth="10" tileheight="10">
  <image source="Solid_blue.PNG" width="200" height="200"/>
 </tileset>
 <tileset firstgid="401" name="Light_green" tilewidth="10" tileheight="10">
  <image source="Light_green.png" width="300" height="300"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="bg" width="32" height="54">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
   eJzt1bENACAMA7DwW/8XJ3EBrAXkwXukRmklKQC4yBz9GXBLAGDPjwd+YMt4nQ7D2QL3vs3R
  </data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

Comment: You need to show the line you get the SIGBRT. There will also be console output. Normally with cocos2d it is that it can't load one of your resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.bounds = [_theMap layerNamed:@"by"];
```

There is no layer named "by" in the file you posted. Are you receiving that error on that line?